# Is there a more efficent way to shadow a user's X11 session than what I'm doing? (C\XLib)

Tags: c, linux, xlib, x11

This assumes the two sessions are on the same box in a multi user desktop environment.  Here is my C code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   Display *d_remote; /* - Display of User you are shadowing - */
   Display *d_local; /* - Your display */
   XImage *img; /* - Used to hold the pixles of the shadowed user's display - */
   Window w, pointer_root, pointer_child;
   XEvent e;
   int s;
   int pointerX, pointerY, winX, winY;
   unsigned int mask;

   //Open your display, if you cant set to NULL 
   d_local = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

   if(d_local == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening 'local' display\n");
    exit(1);
   }

   //Set the XAUTHORITY to teh argument provided.  This is the XAUTHORITY for the remote display
   setenv("XAUTHORITY", argv[2],1);
   d_remote = XOpenDisplay(argv[1]);

   if(d_remote == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening 'remote' display %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
   }


   //Get the size of the remote display
   Window root_remote = RootWindow(d_remote,0);
   XWindowAttributes attr;
   XGetWindowAttributes(d_remote,root_remote,&attr);
   img = XGetImage(d_remote,RootWindow(d_remote,0),0,0,attr.width,attr.height,XAllPlanes(),ZPixmap);

   printf("attr.width = %d, attr.height=%d\n", attr.width, attr.height);

   //Create the window on your display
   s = DefaultScreen(d_local);
   w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d_local, RootWindow(d_local, s), 10, 10, 100, 100, 1,
                           BlackPixel(d_local, s), WhitePixel(d_local, s));

   XSelectInput(d_local, w, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
   XMapWindow(d_local, w);

   while (1) {

      /* - Get the image from the remote display and push it to the local window - */
      img = XGetImage(d_remote,RootWindow(d_remote,0),0,0,attr.width,attr.height,XAllPlanes(),ZPixmap);
      XPutImage(d_local, w, DefaultGC(d_local,0), img, 10, 10, 0, 0, attr.width, attr.height);

      XQueryPointer(d_remote, RootWindow(d_remote,0), &pointer_root, &pointer_child, &pointerX, &pointerY, &winX, &winY, &mask);

      XFillRectangle(d_local, w, DefaultGC(d_local, s), pointerX-10, pointerY-10, 10, 10);
      XFlush(d_local);
      usleep(10);
   }

   XCloseDisplay(d_local);
   XCloseDisplay(d_remote);
   return 0;
}
```

I basically loop, get the raw image of the shadowed user's screen using XGetImage then dump that image into a Window.  This is using massive amounts of CPU.  I can see why considering that I am manipulating large images every centisecond.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?  VNC essentially takes a capture of the user's screen and sends it over the wire (compressed of course) but does not use nearly as much CPU.

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement VNC on a local machine?

Comment: essentially, but I think VNC is overkill and want to make a simple X11 hook that essentially does the same thing.

Comment: You can subscribe for damage events - see exemple here - https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11/blob/master/examples/smoketest/damagetest.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DAMAGE extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/damageproto/damageproto.txt) to get notified when the screen is updated and what part of the screen has changed, so you don't need to grab the whole screen every 10 microseconds if nothing changes (which is much more often than users can see changes if the display is running with a 60 Hz refresh rate), nor would you need to grab the entire screen if all that changed is a 10x10 pixel area where their clock is displayed.